# Can I somehow select text in Windows phone WebBrowser by one tap if another text is already selected?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

User have already selected some word by tap in WebBrowser (windows phone),
1) user needs to tap once to remove selecting
2) user taps again to select some text

Can we do 2 without doing 1?

I can get tap coordinates, if it can help

```
    _webBrowser.MouseLeftButtonUp += _webBrowser_MouseLeftButtonUp;

    void _webBrowser_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var tapPosition = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
    }
```

tapPosition here - it is Point with X and Y properties, where user have taped. I need to select text under this position.
May be there is some javascript function, that I can call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own java script functions.
See this answer it will help you:
[Retrieving Selected Text from Webbrowser control in Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605557/retrieving-selected-text-from-webbrowser-control-in-windows-phone-7)
About delete selection in javascript: [How to remove text selection from selected text which is coming by default on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411760/how-to-remove-text-selection-from-selected-text-which-is-comming-by-default-on-p)